# row to column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table and its value is

```
code Number name
111  a2     'abc'
112  b7     'abc1'
113  a3     'abc2'
113  c5     'abc2'
114  d1     'abc4'
115  s6     'abc3'
116  s9     'a4'
116  s9     'a5'
```

I want to output of my value is

```
code     Number1  number2  name
111      a2       Null     'abc'
112      b7       Null     'abc1'
113      a3       C5       'abc2'
114      d1       Null     'abc4'
115      s6       Null     'abc3'
116      s9       'a4'     'a5'
```

How is it possible from sql Query

Comment: So you want `number2` to contain alternately values from both `Number` and `name`, depending on which is duplicated? That would be something **very** unusual.

Comment: And what happens when code is duplicated but number and name are different?

Comment: You should read up on a subject called [Self Joins](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sqlselfjoin.aspx). You may be able to do what you want by using the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) function in conjunction with Self Joins. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: And what happens when there are 3 rows with same `Number` or `Name` ?

Comment: And what should happen in cases when both `Number` and `name` are duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your output.
It seems to me that the values for the column 'number2' for the row with code=113 comes from the 'Number' column.
Whereas the for the row with code 116, the column 'number2' comes from the 'name' column.

I have started to write the SQL to help:

```
DECLARE @temp table (code INT, Number char(2), Name char(4));
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (111, 'a2', 'abc')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (112, 'b7', 'abc1')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (113, 'a3', 'abc2')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (113, 'c5', 'abc2')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (114, 'd1', 'abc4')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (115, 's6', 'abc3')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (116, 's9', 'a4')
INSERT INTO @temp (code,Number, Name) VALUES (116, 's9', 'a5')


SELECT T1.code, T1.Number, T2.Number, T1.Name
FROM @temp T1
LEFT JOIN @temp T2 ON T1.code = T2.code AND T1.Number=T2.Number AND T1.Name <> T2.Name
WHERE T1.Number = (SELECT MIN(Number) FROM @temp T3 WHERE T3.code = T1.code)
AND T1.Name =  (SELECT MIN(Name) FROM @temp T4 WHERE T4.code = T1.code);
```

Which output is fine except for the row with code 113...
Are you sure about your desired outputs???

Regards,
M